# Determine value of __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ prior to runtime execution

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm currently using `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` when reporting messages (errors, warnings, etc) to a logfile. This ensures there is no confusion regarding which function created the error message.

At the moment, I would like to automatically take the output from the logfile and link it back up with the code which initially created it. The problem is, I cannot determine an efficient method for matching the `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` output in the logfile to the name of the function within the code.

Initially, I was hoping I could just use `gcc -E` to expand all of the macro constants / preprocessor components and directly compare the output of the logfile to the original code. However, `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is not a macro constant -- it is apparently a variable which is determined at runtime. Therefore, `gcc -E` does not work.

From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html:

> These identifiers are not preprocessor macros. In GCC 3.3 and earlier,
>   in C only, `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` were treated as string
>   literals; they could be used to initialize char arrays, and they could
>   be concatenated with other string literals. GCC 3.4 and later treat
>   them as variables, like `__func__`. In C++, `__FUNCTION__` and
>   `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` have always been variables.

Any ideas regarding how I can efficiently match up the output from `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` with the functions in the original code?

Comment: Why not use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__`?

Comment: @bdonlan -- I wasn't aware those were available. In this case, it would require adding additional functionality to the logger, which is possible, but not preferred.

Comment: What do you mean with match up? Find the line in code? If so, why dont you also log `__FILE__` and `__LINE__`?

Comment: @bdonlan -- It is also because I want to be able to get an idea of code-coverage with another tool within the Reporter and therefore want to be able to compare all of the possible run functions, vs the functions which were recorded executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` is a simple and relatively easy solution. The changes to your log functions should be relatively minor in scope as well. If you want code coverage information you're probably better off using GCOV.

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.1/gcc/index.html#toc_Gcov

http://bobah.net/d4d/tools/code-coverage-with-gcov

Answer (score 2):

`__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` is usually used with `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to identify the place in source code.

See [Standard Predefined Macros](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) for more details.